# Reverse a sentence by words using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
str = "it is a boy"
```

I want my console to print the `str` in reverse like `"boy a is it"`. I tried this:

```
console.log(str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')); 
// yob a si ti
```

Comment: Are you sure ? This will work as expected...

Comment: This worked perfectly in the console in chrome.

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zs7tmgn1/. The behaviour you describe would only happen if you did `split('')`, not `split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var revStr = 'it is a boy'.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    let strArr=s.substring(s).split(" ");
    let reverseArr=[];
    strArr.forEach(item=>{
        let reverseItem=item.split('').reverse();
         reverseArr.push(reverseItem.join(""))
    })
    return reverseArr.join(" ")
};

console.log(reverseWords("Let's connect"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).